# SCDF V1.6.0-RELEASE keeps crashing while deploying on PCF

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

My requirement to migrate scheduled tasks to PCF Scheduler integrated in SCDF. When started deploying using manifest file app keeps getting crashed with error message related to database connection. I'm using a user defined service to connect to MySQLDB.

```
2018-08-23 06:02:18.624 INFO 14 --- [ main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.31
2018-08-23 06:02:18.756 INFO 14 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-08-23 06:02:19.432 INFO 14 --- [ main] o.s.c.s.r.PooledDataSourceCreator : Found HikariCP on the classpath. Using it for DataSource connection pooling.
2018-08-23 06:02:19.782 INFO 14 --- [ main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2018-08-23 06:02:20.913 ERROR 14 --- [ main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Access denied for user 'username'@'myappdomain.com' (using password: YES)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:173) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.5.jar!/:na]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:110) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.5.jar!/:na]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1107) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.5.jar!/:na]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:502) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.5.jar!/:na]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:155) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.5.jar!/:na]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:86) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.5.jar!/:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:117) ~[HikariCP-3.1.0.jar!/:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:367) ~[HikariCP-3.1.0.jar!/:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:196) ~[HikariCP-3.1.0.jar!/:na]


Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'username'@'myappdomain.com' (using password: YES)
Current charset is UTF-8. If password has been set using other charset, consider using option 'passwordCharacterEncoding'
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.authentication(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:854) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.5.jar!/:na]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.handleConnectionPhases(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:777) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.5.jar!/:na]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connect(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:451) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.5.jar!/:na]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1103) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.5.jar!/:na]
... 82 common frames omitted

2018-08-23 06:02:20.916 WARN 14 --- [ main] o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup : Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource
org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Access denied for user 'username'@'myappdomain.com' (using password: YES)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:339) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:366) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup.getDatabase(DatabaseLookup.java:72) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.determineDatabase(JpaProperties.java:139) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.14.RELEASE]


Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Access denied for user 'username'@'myappdomain.com' (using password: YES)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.18.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:326) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.18.RELEASE]
... 69 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Access denied for user 'username'@'myappdomain.com' (using password: YES)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:173) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.5.jar!/:na]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:110) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.5.jar!/:na]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1107) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.5.jar!/:na]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:502) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.5.jar!/:na]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:155) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.5.jar!/:na]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:86) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.5.jar!/:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:117) ~[HikariCP-3.1.0.jar!/:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:367) ~[HikariCP-3.1.0.jar!/:na]
... 70 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'username'@'myappdomain.com' (using password: YES)
Current charset is UTF-8. If password has been set using other charset, consider using option 'passwordCharacterEncoding'
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.authentication(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:854) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.5.jar!/:na]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.handleConnectionPhases(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:777) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.5.jar!/:na]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connect(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:451) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.5.jar!/:na]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1103) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.2.5.jar!/:na]
... 82 common frames omitted
```

Manifest file:

```
applications:
- name: dataflow-server
  host: dataflow-server
  memory: 2G
  path: spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry-1.6.0.RELEASE.jar
  buildpack: java_buildpack_offline
  env:
    SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME: dataflow-server
    SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_URL: MY_CLOUDFOUNDRY_URL
    SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ORG: MY_ORG
    SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_SPACE: MY_SPACE
    SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_DOMAIN: MY_DOMAIN
    SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_USERNAME: USERNAME
    SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_PASSWORD: SECRET
    SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_SKIP_SSL_VALIDATION: false
    SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_BUILDPACK: java_buildpack_offline
  services: 
  - RabbitMQ
  - mysql-service
```

This is the same manifest that I used for my previous version V1.3.0-RELEASE deployment and it worked as expected.

Comment: Well, check the error message: `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'username'@'myappdomain.com'` seems like you dont have the correct credentials.

Comment: @mrkernelpanic The same DB service is used by another version of SCDF which works fine. I don't think it's credentials issue. Well my doubt here is why is the app trying to connect to Hikari DB whereas the connection available on classpath is MYSQL?

Answer (score 0):

As of 1.5, we have switched the connection pool mechanism to be managed by Hikari. Spring Boot switched it as a default, too. More background as to why can be found from [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow#2169](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/2169), [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry#417](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/issues/417), and [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry#415](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/issues/415).

With this support, you can control the pool-size through declarative configurations - see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-connection-pool).

Apart from the new config properties for customizations, we do not have to set anything new in v1.5 and over.

It'd be good to review the entire stacktrace from when you `cf push` and all the way till the errors occur. Also, you can edit the post to include what you see in the `VCAP_SERVIVCES` for scdf-server's environment. It could be that the JSON parsing for datasource creds from the CUPs service is in a different format than what the `spring-cloud-connector` can interpret, which we rely on internally.

Comment: SCDFs <pre><code>VCAP_SERVICES</code></pre> had the exact same uri and credentials specified in CUPs. On going through the complete exception trace I see this line <pre><code>Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set</code></pre>. My understanding is that Spring Boot will detect the driver to load on the fly depending on the connection on the classpath.

Comment: Uploaded stacktrace here - https://github.com/prasad91/Test/blob/master/.gitignore/SDCF_exception

Comment: I've debugged SCDF V1.6 source in local and saw that app is using mariadb driver to create the connection using HikariCP. Is there anyway where I can use the Tomcat JDBC and Mysql driver to connect to database in SCDF V1.6 as the same config was working in SCDF V1.3?

Comment: To you mean the tomcat connection pool?  We switched to use Hikari since it is generally considered the better connection pool following the change in Spring Boot which did the same.  We don't expose a declarative way to configure which connection pool implementation to use.

Comment: I don't think it is a connection pool issue though, since the exception came up from `at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.authentication`  I used mysql:5.6 and SCDF 1.6.3 local and it started correctly.  Will need to try and reproduce on Cloud Foundry.